# Checking linux Kernel for RT-Preempt Patch

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded

How to know whether a particular patch is applied to the kernel? Especially RT-Preempt Patch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case of preempt you can just use `uname`:

```
uname -v
#23 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Oct 16 11:52:29 CET 2012
```

The string *PREEMPT* shows that you use a kernel version with the realtime patch.

Some other patches might also changes the `uname` string. So it might also be a help. If this is not the case you can try to look at your `.config`. The file could be found in the `/boot` directory or (if enabled) by using `cat /proc/config.gz`. Maybe there is also a version in `/usr/src/linux` (or where you put the kernel sources).

If you found the config file you can grep for specific settings and find out if a patch is used.